# How (or in which file) does JShell store its configuration settings?

Tags: java, jshell

The doc says:

> Remember that the startup scripts are loaded into the current session
>   only when the state is reset. The contents of the script is stored,
>   not a reference to the script.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/scripts.htm#JSHEL-GUID-AC2A6582-6A9A-48B1-ABBF-4C9536CDFD07)

For example,

```
/set start -retain mystartscript.jsh
```

But where does it store the contents of *mystartscript.jsh*?

Comment: The answer to this would mostly be in the direction that the Jshell tool supports such customization using the `Feedback` object(internal class) that a user would modify using the flags on the command line.

Comment: @nullpointer How did you find this out?

Comment: Looking into the code of JDK.

Comment: I don't want to manually set a list of classpaths upon startup, so I was trying to locate a .jshellrc file somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean to set up a default classpath to be used while starting up a jshell?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164562/discussion-between-nawk-and-nullpointer).

Answer (score 0):

Using a relative filename like you do in your example:

```
/set start -retain mystartscript.jsh
```

JShell would look for `mystartscript.jsh` in [*`user.home`*]/*`mystartscript.jsh`*

You could also give it an absolute file path:

```
/set start -retain /my_custom_jshell_scripts/mystartscript.jsh
```

Robert Field—the JShell lead architect—explains in [*this tutorial*](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rfield/tutorial/JShellTutorial.html#start-up-scripts) how to (*re*)set/unset JShell's built-in `DEFAULT` startup scripts plus custom `.jsh`startup scripts.